# Is using the super keyword allowed on static properties of classes?

Tags: javascript, class, super, rollupjs

I know that the `super` keyword can be used to reference inherited properties and methods in a class. It can also be used in static methods and call `super.staticMethod()`. Is it okay to use the `super` keyword on static properties? Rollup says that it isn't okay, and I came across this problem while compiling ESModules to a CommonJs file.

**Rollup is fine with this**

```js
class A {
  static m() {
    return 1;
  }
}
class B extends A {
  static m() {
    return super.m() + 1;
  }
}
console.log("A", A.m());
console.log("B", B.m());
```

Here there are static methods on classes `A` and `B`. B calls `super.m()`, which is like calling `A.m()`.

**Rollup is NOT fine with this**

```js
class A {
  static score = 5;
  static info = {
    prop1: "hi",
    prop2: "hello"
  }
}
class B extends A {
  static score = super.score + 5;
  static info = {
    ...super.info,
    prop3: "welcome",
    prop4: "good morning"
  }
}
console.log("A", A.score, A.info);
console.log("B", B.score, B.info);
```

Still, I don't see what's wrong with the second example. When I run it, it works without any errors. Is it bad or invalid javascript, or is rollup just complaining even though it's valid javascript? When I replace `super` with `A` (for example, `A.score` instead of `super.score`), it works.

**Rollup Error**

[!] Error: 'super' keyword outside a method

**My `rollup.config.js` file**

```
export default {
    input: "index.js",
    output: {
        file: "commonjs/index.js",
        format: "cjs"
    }
}
```

Comment: Does rollup support class fields at all? If yes, what transpiler plugin are you using? Iirc rollup itself is only a bundler.

Comment: I'm not sure. I'm also not sure what lirc means. I have a npm module written with ESModules, and using rollup so people can use it with CommonJS. I used rollup with `npm install rollup --save-dev`, made a `rollup.config.js` file, and have a npm build script which is `rollup -c`. Then I do `npm run build`.

Comment: [iirc](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/IIRC). Can you show your `rollup.config.js` please?

Comment: Edit: I will just put it in post instead of unformatted comment.

Answer (score 1):

Static class fields [are still an experimental proposal](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features).

> Is it okay to use the `super` keyword on static properties?

Yes, probably.

If I interpret the current specification draft correctly, there is [no early error](https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#sec-static-semantics-early-errors) from using `super.…` or `super[…]` in a class field, only `super(…)` and `arguments` are syntax errors - and there are [no early errors](https://tc39.es/proposal-static-class-features/#sec-static-semantics-early-errors) specifically for `static` fields either. The field initialisers [are evaluated as if their code was in an anonymous method](https://tc39.es/proposal-class-fields/#runtime-semantics-class-field-definition-evaluation), where they have access to a receiver (`this` value) and home object (`super` base).
However, there appears to be [an editorial issue](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-static-class-features/issues/38) about how the class value is passed to the definition algorithm, and it's not inconceivable that the decision to allow `super` is reevaluated. That the parser used by Rollup disagrees with Chrome here is a bug, but we don't know in which of the two implementations.

Comment: It's not just chrome. Node.js is also okay with it. I will open an issue on rollup's github.

Comment: @programmerRaj Well chrome and node are using the same js engine, so no surprise there. You should try with Firefox and Safari instead.